# Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1

Tags: syslog

My syslog is filled with this message, and when it triggers it adds about 100 lines a second. Any way I can try to figure out what is causing it?

Extraction of what it looks like

```
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11158]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11155]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11155]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11128]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11133]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11171]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11158]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11147]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11169]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11163]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11155]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11151]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11166]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11164]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11141]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
Dec 17 17:33:28 glocknet systemd-udevd[11170]: Process '/bin/chmod 0666 ' failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Have the same did you find anything out about it?

Comment: @TimAlexander I have not yet unfortunately.